# Cannot find module 'express-session'

Tags: node.js, redis

I am trying to run `sparkleshare-dashboard`. This is an open source project you can see it here 
https://github.com/tommyd3mdi/sparkleshare-dashboard.

The project use `Node.JS` and `Redis` and i have no experience with both. I did setup the environment as described in the help file and then i try to run file `app.js` from command line using 'node' command but i got this error.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express-session'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Imports\sparkleshare-dashboard\app.js:5:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Maybe i didn't provide enough information but i am expecting that may be some of you guys has done some work on `sparkleshare` project and may someone can help me in this.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on the INSTALL.md file? https://github.com/tommyd3mdi/sparkleshare-dashboard/blob/master/INSTALL.md

Comment: yes i follow these intsturctions

Answer (score 13):

The reason is likely your ">" operator for express in the package.json.
Express 4.0 is out now and the complete middleware concept changed.
You need to install [these middlewares](https://github.com/expressjs) manually.
"express-session" is one of the 4.0 middlewares.

I recommend to read

http://scotch.io/bar-talk/expressjs-4-0-new-features-and-upgrading-from-3-0
and
https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x

Additionally some users were confused that the github repo is named just "session" but

```
npm install express-session
```

is correct.

Comment: and btw : you should inform the author of this (nice) project to make it compatible with express4

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed `express-session`. You can check for the directory inside your node_modules folder or you can also chekc your dependencies inside your package.json file